# Кнопка выподающего списка не отрабатывает

Tags: javascript, three.js

Столкнулся с проблемой, кнопка вы подающего списка не отрабатывает

Вот код:

```
    var controls = new function () {
        this.rotationSpeed = 0.02;
        this.bouncingSpeed = 0.03;
    };
    
    var controls1 = new function () {
       this.site = "hangge.com";
     };
     
   var controls2 = new function () {
       this.rotationSpeed = 0; 
     };

    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    const geometryFolder  = gui.addFolder("камера");
    //geometryFolder.add(controls1, 'расположение камеры',  [ 'google.com', 'hangge.com', '163.com' ]); // nerabotaet
    //geometryFolder.add(controls1, 'расположение камеры',  {'google.com', 'hangge.com', '163.com' }); //n
  //geometryFolder.add(controls1, 'расположение камеры',  [ this.site, this.site1, this.site2]);
//  //geometryFolder.add(controls1, 'расположение камеры',  { this.site, this.site1, this.site2});
    geometryFolder.add(controls, 'rotationSpeed', 0, 0.5);
    geometryFolder.add(controls, 'bouncingSpeed', 0, 0.5);
    const primitiveFolder =  gui.addFolder("примитивы");
    primitiveFolder.add(controls2, 'rotationSpeed', { Stopped: 0, Slow: 0.02, Fast: 5 });
   //  primitiveFolder.add(controls2, 'скорость', { стоп: 0, медлено: 0.02, быстро: 5 });
```

Вот так работает.

Но если я хочу проучить кнопку с русским текстом то у меня не запускается

```
primitiveFolder.add(controls2, 'скорость', { стоп: 0, медлено: 0.02, быстро: 5 });
```

Вот не знаю как запустить русский текст.

---

Добавил строчку как Виктор предложил

```
 primitiveFolder.add(controls2, 'скорость', { 'стоп': 0, 'медленно': 0.02, 'быстро': 5 });
```

Увы не отрабатывает, возможно это из за моего браузера??

Comment: ```primitiveFolder.add(controls2, 'скорость', { 'стоп': 0, 'медленно': 0.02, 'быстро': 5 });```

Comment: @ВикторКарев увы тоже не заработало. Возможно это из-за браузера.

Comment: А свойства по типу `стоп`, `медленно` .. точно можно писать на русском?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так заработало, подсказали на сайте библиотеки
https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-create-button-in-russan-languages/50227

```
 geometryFolder.add(controls2, "rotationSpeed", { 'стоп': 0, 'медленно': 0.02, 'быстро': 5 }).name("скорость");
```